# Comparing column enteries with an array or a list

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe , containing a column (User ID) containing enteries : 1,2,3 ... etc and I want to compare those enteries with a list/array and find out which numbers are missing ?

How do I achieve that? How do I compare that user_ID column with an Array (a)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of set-magic would do the trick if you're looking for which numbers are missing from `a` in your case:

```py
a = range(1, 101)
# if values in DataFrame are stored as floats/ints
missing_from_range = set(a).difference(data1['user_iD'])

# if values in dataframe are stored as strings/objects
missing_from_range = set(a).difference(data1['user_iD'].astype(int))
```

Comment: Hey Stefan, This isn't working. I'm getting an output of as the complete list of array again, It's not subtracting/ generating differences between array (a) and column user_iD

Comment: Are you sure your `user_iD` column is stored as integers?

Comment: oh , my bad it was object..
Solved it thanks stefan for the help :)